# I am trying to get the program to only display months that are starting with the letter J but I can't get it to as it only displays one month

Tags: java, arrays

This is part of the code where I try to get the program to display all months starting with the letter J
It only shows the same month three times

```
String[] jMonths = new String[12];

for(int i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {

    for(int j = 0; j < jMonths.length; j++) {

        if(months[i].charAt(0) == 'J') {
            jMonths[j] = months[i];
        }
    }
}


String message = jMonths[0]+" " + jMonths[5] +" " + jMonths[6];

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

Please help me! Thank You

Comment: Can you Show declaration and initialization of months[]?

Comment: You don't need the second for loop

Comment: you are overwritting do not use two for loops one is enough and use variable j in first loop and increment it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do not require an inner loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < months.length; i++){
    if(months[i].charAt(0) == 'J') {
        jMonths[i] = months[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> you are overwritting do not use two for loops one is enough and use
>   variable j in first loop and increment it

```
 String[] jMonths = new String[12];

    for(int i = 0,j=0; i < months.length; i++,j++) {

            if(months[i].charAt(0) == 'J') {
                jMonths[j] = months[i];
            }
        }



    String message = jMonths[0]+" " + jMonths[5] +" " + jMonths[6];

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inner `for` loop is not correct. In fact, you don't even need that inner `for` loop, you can just use `StringBuilder` instead, e.g.:

```
StringBuilder jMonths = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++){
    if (months[i].charAt(0) == 'J'){
        jMonths.append(months[i] + " ");
    }
}

String message = jMonths.toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess case could be your issue but it's hard to tell with the information here. 
I would recommend using:

```
months[i].toLowerCase().startsWith("j")
```

instead of:

```
months[i].charAt(0) == 'J'
```

There's a lot of places in your algorithim where things could be going wrong, so simplifying it might help. I.e:

```
StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        for(String month : jMonths){
            if(month.toLowerCase().startsWith("j")){
                message.append(month+" ");
            }
        }
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message.toString().trim());
```

Comment: this is the output i get   "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Main.main(Main.java:35)

Process completed. "

Answer (score 0):

whay using two loops:

```
List<String> jMonths = new ArrayList<String> ();
for (int i = 0; i < months.length; i++){
    if (months[i].charAt(0) == 'J' or months[i].charAt(0) == 'j'){
        jMonths.add(months[i]);
    }
}

for (String month : jMonths) System.out.println(month);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i would have been there i will not use any loops.
We have only to display the months which start with letter J First you define a array containing all the month names and then search the month which starts with J could you not simply print them.

e.g. String mons="January"+"June"+"July";

There are only 12 months and only 3 which starts with J need not to make a algo for it.